# Converter String para Date (request.getParameter)

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet

Tenho um formulário em `JSP` que realiza um cadastro que possui uma data.

```
<form  method="Post" action="InserirCompromisso">
            titulo : <input type="text" name="titulo" required="true">
            local : <input type="text" name="local" required="true">
            data : <input type="text" name="data">
            <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar">

        </form>
```

E ai que está o problema.Como eu faço para converter essa `String` do `Input` utilizando o `request.getParameter` como fiz com as outras `Strings`? A maneira que fiz no meu `Servlet` não está rodando.Alguém poderia me ajudar.

Segue meu `Servlet` abaixo.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String Titulo = request.getParameter("titulo");
    String Local = request.getParameter("local");
    String dataEmTexto = request.getParameter("data");
    Calendar data = null;

    try {
        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(dataEmTexto);
        data = Calendar.getInstance();
        data.setTime(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        out.println("Erro de conversão da data");
        return; //para a execução do método
    }

    Compromisso compromisso = new Compromisso();
    compromisso.setTitulo(Titulo);
    compromisso.setLocal(Local);
    compromisso.setData(data);


    CompromissoDAO dao = new CompromissoDAO();
    String retorno = dao.inserir(compromisso);
    if(retorno.equals("sucesso")){

        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");

    }else{
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print("<html>");
        out.print("<h2>Não foi possivel inserir</h2>");
        out.print("<br>");
        out.print("</html>");
    }

}
```

Comment: Tiago, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Você precisa dizer qual o erro. O código parece certo.

Comment: Ola utluiz.Obrigado por responder.

Está dando um erro nessa linha:

compromisso.setData(data);

O erro é esse : 

incompatible types :  Calendar cannot be converted to Date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executei aqui e deu certo. Passa a data ao invés do Calendar. Persistência precisa ir dentro do try-catch também.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String Titulo = request.getParameter("titulo");
    String Local = request.getParameter("local");
    String dataEmTexto = request.getParameter("data");


        try {
            Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(dataEmTexto);
            Compromisso compromisso = new Compromisso();
            compromisso.setTitulo(Titulo);
            compromisso.setLocal(Local);
            compromisso.setData(date);
            CompromissoDAO dao = new CompromissoDAO();
            String retorno = dao.inserir(compromisso);
            if (retorno.equals("sucesso")) {

                response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");

            } else {
                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                out.print("<html>");
                out.print("<h2>Não foi possivel inserir</h2>");
                out.print("<br>");
                out.print("</html>");
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            out.println("Erro de conversão da data");
            return; //para a execução do método
        }   

}
```

Obs: Você nem precisa desse Calendar. Nem tá usando no seu modelo.

Comment: Vou tentar amanhã Mariana.Muito obrigado pela ajuda. :)